# Change number written in scientific notation in filenames

Tags: linux, filenames, rename, numbering

I'm going to make a video of image files, but the filenames contain numbers in scientific notation, so the ordering of the name will not be correct.

The filenames are in this format:

```
ABC_1.000000E-01.png ~ ABC_1.100000E+01.png,
DEF_1.000000E-01.png ~ DEF_1.100000E+01.png,
GHI_1.000000E-01.png ~ GHI_1.100000E+01.png,
.
.
.
```

If I change the number notation used for the numbers, the order is not correct again, so I want to change it as below.

```
ABC_001.png ~ ABC_110.png,
DEF_001.png ~ DEF_110.png,
GHI_001.png ~ GHI_110.png,
.
.
.
```

How may I do this on my Linux system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also

```
ls -1 *.png | LC_ALL=C awk -F[._] '{TMP=$2 "." $3; printf "mv %s  %s_%03d.%s\n", $0, $1, 10*TMP, $4}'                  
mv ABC_1.000000E-01.png  ABC_001.png
mv ABC_1.100000E+01.png  ABC_110.png
mv DEF_1.000000E-01.png  DEF_001.png
mv DEF_1.100000E+01.png  DEF_110.png
mv GHI_1.000000E-01.png  GHI_001.png
mv GHI_1.100000E+01.png  GHI_110.png
```

It uses `awk` to isolate and convert the number in scientific notation and output its tenfold value as a zero padded integer. Pipe through e.g. `sh` if happy with the result.

Comment: As you showed me, mv ABC_1.0000E-01.png ABC_001.png... I can see, but the file has not been changed. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Read the post carefully, esp. the last sentence. ```| sh ``` will execute the ```mv``` commands.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that will find every png file on the current directory and rename them accordingly. Mind that it won't overwrite existing files.

---

Here's the preview of the work

```
./DEF_1.100000E+01.png - ./DEF_11.00.png
./DEF_1.000000E-01.png - ./DEF_0.10.png
./GHI_1.000000E-01.png - ./GHI_0.10.png
./ABC_1.100000E+01.png - ./ABC_11.00.png
./GHI_1.100000E+01.png - ./GHI_11.00.png
./ABC_1.000000E-01.png - ./ABC_0.10.png
```

Before the script

```
$ ls
ABC_1.000000E-01.png  DEF_1.000000E-01.png  GHI_1.000000E-01.png  script.sh
ABC_1.100000E+01.png  DEF_1.100000E+01.png  GHI_1.100000E+01.png
```

After the script

```
$ ls
ABC_0.10.png   DEF_0.10.png   GHI_0.10.png   script.sh
ABC_11.00.png  DEF_11.00.png  GHI_11.00.png
```

---

script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.png")
do
    number=$(echo "${file}" | cut -d'_' -f 2)
    number=$(basename "${number}" .png)
    number=$(echo "${number}" | awk '{ printf("%.2f\n",$1) }')

    filename=$(echo "${file}" | cut -d'_' -f 1)

    mv -n "${file}" "${filename}_${number}.png"
done
```

Comment: Don't loop over the output of `find` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697). Using `cut` on strings is costly, just use standard parameter substitutions instead, e.g. `filename=${file%%_*}`.

Comment: Thank you, but I just removed the exponent number and the order I wanted was not resolved.
It's a problem where 10.10 ~ 11.00 are stuck between 1.00 and 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload -Uz zmv
$ zmv -n '(*_)(<->.<->E[+-]<->)(.png)' '$1${(l[3][0])$(( ($2*10)|0 ))}$3'
mv -- ABC_1.000000E-01.png ABC_001.png
mv -- ABC_1.100000E+01.png ABC_110.png
mv -- DEF_1.000000E-01.png DEF_001.png
mv -- DEF_1.100000E+01.png DEF_110.png
mv -- GHI_1.000000E-01.png GHI_001.png
mv -- GHI_1.100000E+01.png GHI_110.png
```

(and remove the `-n` for dry run if happy).

Similar with the `perl`-based variants of `rename` (sometimes called `prename` or `perl-rename` to disambiguate it from the (unrelated and much more limited) `rename` command from `util-linux`):

```
$ rename -n 's{_\K\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+(?=\.png\Z)}{sprintf "%03d", $&*10}e' ./*.png
rename(./ABC_1.000000E-01.png, ./ABC_001.png)
rename(./ABC_1.100000E+01.png, ./ABC_110.png)
rename(./DEF_1.000000E-01.png, ./DEF_001.png)
rename(./DEF_1.100000E+01.png, ./DEF_110.png)
rename(./GHI_1.000000E-01.png, ./GHI_001.png)
rename(./GHI_1.100000E+01.png, ./GHI_110.png)
```

The parallel between the two:

- perl's `\d+` matches one or more decimal digits while zsh's `<->` matches strings representing any decimal number (form of `<x-y>` without bounds), so are essentially the same.
- `sprintf "%03d"` converts to integer and pads with 0. `$(( number|0 ))` converts to integer in zsh, while the `l[3][0]` does the padding.

Differences:

- `zmv` will do sanity checks (such as conflicts for `x_1E+2.png` vs `x_10E+1.png` for instance or target files already there) before doing any renaming.
- zsh's `l` parameter expansion flag does padding but also truncates to the specified width. So, `1.2E+3` (1200) would be truncated to `200`, while `sprintf "%03d"` would leave it as `1200`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it seems that zsh is not installed in the operating system. And the error '-n' occurs in the 'rename'.

Comment: @KitaeKim, `-n` is for dry-run like for the zmv approach. You also need one of the `perl` `rename` implementations, not the one from `util-linux`.